# Search in rails activerecord column with datatype string is slow when I send an integer

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have a `Registrations` table with a nearly a million rows. On this table is a field `my_string_id_field` that has an index. `my_string_id_field` is a `string` type, however many of the ids are integers.

When I do a search such as:
`Registraions.where(my_string_id_field: 12345)` rails considers that an Integer and does not end up using the index on `my_string_id_field`. This ends up being super slow!

The sql for this comes out as 
`` SELECT `registrations`.* FROM `registrations` WHERE `registrations`.`my_string_id_field` = 12345 ``

If I do a search such as:
`Registraions.where(my_string_id_field: '12345')` rails will send the parameter as a String, mysql uses the index, and things are speedy again.

The sql for this comes out as 

`` SELECT `registrations`.* FROM `registrations` WHERE `registrations`.`my_string_id_field` = '12345' ``

I know I could simply do something like `Registraions.where(my_string_id_field: var.to_s)` and have ruby convert it to a string, but then I have to remember to do that every time. Is there some way to force rails to recognize that the field it is searching on is a string datatype and pass whatever I pass it as a string always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a scope like

```
scope :search, lambda{|id| where(my_string_id_field: id.to_s)}
```

and then you can use this scope, anywhere .

Comment: Works for me. Although for Rails 3 and later I prefer to just use a class method, but they end up doing the same thing. Thanks.